# Microsoft Access VBA invalid use of property error

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

So, I have this class where I call a few classes where data is checked. They give back an error class, named Failcase. Now I get an error when I first set the error to true.

The error states:

> Invalid use of Property.

```
Private Sub btnImport_Click()
    Dim fail As Failcase
    Set fail.Success = True       '<---- This is where the error occures

    Set fail = ImportCheckSpec(Me.txtImportSpec)

    If fail.Success Then
        MsgBox "Error " + CStr(fail.Code) + ": " + fail.Message, vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set fail = ImportCheckDate(Me.txtDateTime)

    If fail.Success Then
        MsgBox "Error " + CStr(fail.Code) + ": " + fail.Message, vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Success"
    End If
End Sub
```

The Failcase class looks like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Success As Boolean
Public Code As Integer
Public Message As String
```

---

I use:

- Microsoft Access 2013
- VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using OOP without creating a new object of class `Failcase`. Try this in the module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim fail As New failcase
    fail.Success = True
    Debug.Print fail.Success

End Sub
```

In the class:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_bSuccess As Boolean

Public Property Get Success() As Boolean

    Success = m_bSuccess

End Property

Public Property Let Success(ByVal bNewValue As Boolean)

    m_bSuccess = bNewValue

End Property
```

Thus, you would achieve encapsulation. With it, you may set a bit more rules for accessing your property - https://www.google.com/search?q=encapsulation+oop&oq=encapsulation+oop&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3599j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

The code above was an example of [early binding](https://www.google.com/search?q=encapsulation%20oop&oq=encapsulation%20oop&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3599j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=vba%20early%20binding). This is another one, example of late binding, doing the same:

```
Public Sub TestLateBinding()

    Dim fail As Object
    Set fail = New failcase
    fail.Success = True
    Debug.Print fail.Success

End Sub
```

Early and late binding have different pros and cons.

Comment: Since this is not a high traffic question, I am going to say thank you. This truly is an example of an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It works like this.

```
Dim fail As New Failcase
fail.Success = True
```